# How to set image source of Image Class to MapIcon Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a imagine source with Uri type for my image, and i want to put as source of my MapIcon, because i need to resize my image.

```
MapIcon mapIcon = new MapIcon();

        mapIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.25, 0.9);
        //mapIcon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icons/map.png"));

        mapIcon.Location = geoposition.Coordinate.Point;
        mapIcon.Title = "Você está aqui";

        MapControl1.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);

Image im = new Image();
        im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icons/view.png"));
        im.Width = 65;
        im.Height = 65;
```

how can i put my Image inside to MapIcon ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mentioned in all the pages I've been reading on this issue .... to use a local file in the Assets folder as your map icon you must add it to the project ... in Solution Explorer expand Assets, rt click Assets, click Add, select Existing Item, navigate to your project's Assets folder, then select your image file.

Answer (score -1):

```
Geopoint myPoint;    
BasicGeoposition location = new BasicGeoposition();
var locator = new Geolocator();
                locator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
                var position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                myPoint = position.Coordinate.Point;

MapIcon MapIcon = new MapIcon();
MapIcon.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = myPoint.Position.Latitude,
            Longitude = myPoint.Position.Longitude
        });
        MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
        location.Latitude = myPoint.Position.Latitude;
        location.Longitude = myPoint.Position.Longitude;


        Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(location);
        MapLocationFinderResult result =
           await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);
        //MapIcon.Title = result.Locations[0].Address.Street;
        MapIcon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icons/view.png"));
        YourMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon);
```